# error transfer NSString to delegate

Tags: xcode, delegates, nsstring, segue

I have error:

```
[2194:c07] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Event' 
2012-12-08 12:00:57.505 eventCost[2194:c07] -[Event setType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7456dd0
2012-12-08 12:00:57.523 eventCost[2194:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Event setType:]: unrecognized selector
```

I have protocol at my addEventController:@protocol

```
AddEventControllerDelegate
- (void) addEventControllerDidSave:(NSString *) typeText;
- (void) addEventControllerDidCancel:(Event *) personToDelete;
@end
```

the implementation of the protocol:

```
- (void) addEventControllerDidCancel:(Event *)EventToDelete{

    [[self currentPerson] removeEventsObject:EventToDelete];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) addEventControllerDidSave:(NSString *)typeText{

    Event *newEvent = [[Event alloc]init];
    [newEvent setType:typeText];

    [currentPerson addEventsObject:newEvent];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

also I have this segue for add new event:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"addEvent"])
    {
        AddEventController *aec = (AddEventController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        aec.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

I just try to add new Event with type property but I have this error and I don't understand what wrong..

Comment: Show the methods defined in your "`Event`" .h interface file...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to send an `NSManagedObject` an `init` message.

You need to use `- (id)initWithEntity: (NSEntityDescription *) entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context`

see the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html